# Metadata Api name of "Manage Public Lightning Email Templates"?

Tags: profile, metadata

As the title says, what is the API name for **Manage Public Lightning Email Templates**?

[image]

Although I enabled/disabled it and fetched profile, I do not find any Metadata API name matching this `userPermissions`. Is the Name completely different from label? Unfortunately I am not finding any online reference also

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Metadata API name 'CreateLtngTempInPub' for Manage Public Lightning Email Templates.

Below is 'userPermissions' for same

```
<userPermissions>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <name>CreateLtngTempInPub</name>
</userPermissions>
```

Set value of 'Manage Public Lightning Email Templates' to true on the Profile level and retrieve you can check above name in userPermissions.

Comment: awesome! how did you find it?

Comment: Retrieved metadata of profile with the two scenarios (checkbox checked/unchecked) and was able to narrow down and find an API name.  Thanks.

Comment: Strange, I did same thing but it did not get this metadata when true/false